# gwt - error in web mode when calling to async function

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, authentication, war

I made a simple Login app in WGT which asking the user for user and password, validates the details "hard coded" (no data base involved) in the server side, and then shows a simple table that contains some information...

When I run the application in Eclipse - all works good
but after I executed to WAR file and run the HTML file in the browser, after clicking the Login botton I got:

```
 "Unable to initiate the asynchronous service invocation (GreetingService_Proxy.greetServer) -- check the network connection"
```

I read about the problem and added a few lined to the moudle.xml file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.core.Core" />
<add-linker name="xs" />
```

but now i got this error:
on IE9:

The URL file:///C:/Users/meital/Desktop/workspace2/New%20folder/meitalgwt/greet is invalid or violates the same-origin security restriction

on firefox:

```
(NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI): Access to restricted URI denied code: 1012 INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1 DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2 HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3 WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: 4 INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5 NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6 NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7 NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8 NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9 INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10 INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11 SYNTAX_ERR: 12 INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13 NAMESPACE_ERR: 14 INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15 VALIDATION_ERR: 16 TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: 17 SECURITY_ERR: 18 NETWORK_ERR: 19 ABORT_ERR: 20 URL_MISMATCH_ERR: 21 QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR: 22 TIMEOUT_ERR: 23 INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24 DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25 result: 2152924148 filename: file:///C:/Users/meital/Desktop/workspace2/New%20folder/meitalgwt/012B81D90198FC382E15B5001E0AD8FE.cache.js lineNumber: 579 columnNumber: 0 inner: null data: null
```

anyone know what can it be?

Its important to say that I'm new in GWT, so please include in your answer any basic step that i might miss...

Thanks!!!

Comment: As I understand, you deploy a war file, shown the page in a browser, that try to access to a file your local computer. That cause the same origin policy problem. Have you got an absolute reference on any link or form?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you aren't running a server, and instead just trying to run the whole app from files on your hard drive. The `xs` linker you are using allows you to run the JavaScript from a directory, but if there is no server, there is nothing for your async service call to talk to.

Instead, consider using Tomcat or Jetty as a server, deploying your war inside them, and starting them on your computer. Once you've done this, the linker line enabling the `xs` linker will no longer be necessary.

Check out the Deploying page in the GWT documentation on more about this - you need to not only deploy to a *server*, but one that can run the RPC service as well: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideDeploying#DevGuideDeployingServletContainerUsingRPC

There is of course another option, but it probably isn't helpful for you: remove the async service calls. If you aren't calling into a server, then you don't need to have any software running that service.